# VMWare Windows XP session says 'insufficient disk space' for a 6 gb file but there's 14 gb free

Tags: windows-xp, filesystems, vmware

My VMWare Windows XP session says 'insufficient disk space' to copy in a 6 gb database dump but there's more than 14 gb free :( .

It's a growable disk. It;s currently 5.5 GB in size.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this an `NTFS` volume?  If it's `FAT`, you're overrunning the [limit](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs_vs_fat.htm) on file size (~4GB).

Also, this may be a quirk with `growable` volumes... maybe try [resizing](http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-7471)?  Or change the [`disktype`](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/80342) to `preallocated`?

Comment: It's fat32. Stupid pre-configured vm :-( .

Comment: Hahaha... sorry, can you re-format?  Any way to split the db dump?

Comment: I was able to convert to ntfs with 'convert.exe' that ships with Windows... Took under 10 minutes:) .

Answer (score -1):

I thought the filesize limit in xp was 2gb. Or are we not talking about 1 file here?

Comment: Only on FAT32. There are lots of people viewing DVD movies in XP :)